# how can I add (bound) an external image as an overlay on top of the full portion of nokia (here) map using 'groundoverlay' function?

Tags: google-maps, here-api

In google map api, I styled the features and colors differently for water and landscape. I bound an old transparent paper image as an overlay on the top of the google map api, but for nokia here map api, I could not find anything like that to do the same things. I only found to add an image bound to a specific `geo.BoundingBox` area using the `ImageProvider` class, but this is not what I want. I want the things that I did for google also something similar for **Nokia Here** map API (if possible for the latest version 3.0 would be best). @Jason Fox

Comment: Do you have a link to the google maps version for reference? Not sure what you are looking for... Do you want a paper effect everywhere? Does it stick to the map or does it move with the viewport?

Comment: @echom , It has to stick with the map. For Google, I placed one transparent image on the top of the map interface, the all interactivity (e.g. zooming in & out) of the map remains same. Below is the example: var paperMap; google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() { var bounds = map.getBounds(); paperMap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay( "css/map-filter-mask.png", bounds); paperMap.setMap(map); }); I am sorry that I don't have enough points to upload the output. I want to do the same thing for nokia/here map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a ground overlay for that... I didn't try your code but just reading it, I get that everytime the map goes idle (doesn't move/zoom anymore) you want a transparent png to fill the entire screen right?

In that case, why go through the geo-reality at all? After the map stops your png must fill the screen, no matter where in the world you are. So the geo-bounds of the map are completely irrelevant to the problem.

Instead just append an HTML image to the map's viewport element.

```js
var map; //your Map instance

var image = new Image("css/map-filter-mask.png");
var viewport = map.getViewPort().element;

image.style.width = "100%";
image.style.height = "100%";

map.getViewPort().element.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it didn't work for me. Actually, the interactivity (moving, zooming, circles, polylines) of the map has to work, I just want to change the outlook [old historic map (that's why I use an transparent old paper image on the top of the map) and the different color styles for water & landscape in the map]. I already did it for Google map, but, now I want to do it for nokia/here map. Do you have any solution for it? –